# Force a single font for all unicode glyphs

Tags: fonts, unicode

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.4.1 in a GUI on OS X.  I want to force every character to be displayed using just a single font rather than allowing Emacs to choose a supposedly most appropriate.  I understand that no font will include every glyph, but I use a limited subset of unicode which many good fonts cover satisfactorily.

I've seen a lot of talk about using the unicode-fonts package to set fonts for ranges of characters, but I don't want to have a thousand extra lines in my config to set every block separately.

How can I simply stop Emacs from automatically mapping different glyphs to different fonts?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `(set-fontset-font t nil MY-FONT)` where `MY-FONT` is the name of your font?

Comment: @lunaryorn Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that just now and I still get different fonts for different characters.  I tried setting my font to Pragmata Pro and end up getting Menlo unicode glyphs (as verified by `describe-char`).

Comment: @user227's answer worked for me. l just wanted to use Terminus in Emacs in GUI mode and prevent Emacs from using glyphs for quotes that had larger widths. I added this to my init file: `(set-fontset-font t nil "fontset-default")`. P.S.: It's necessary to set the `default` face (Menu bar: `Options > Set Default Font... > {choose font}` then `Options > Save Options`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Playing with Emacs’ fontsets definitions should be the answer.

After reading

- [Fontsets docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Defining-Fontsets.html#Defining-Fontsets):

> The startup fontset will use the font that you specify, or a variant
> with a different registry and encoding, for all the characters that
> are supported by that font, and fallback on ‘fontset-default’ for
> other characters.

> [If some characters](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fontsets.html#Fontsets) appear on the screen as empty boxes or hex codes,
> this means that the fontset in use for them has no font for those
> characters.

- *set-fontset-font* description:

> TARGET may be a cons; (FROM . TO), where FROM and TO are characters.
> In that case, use FONT-SPEC for all characters in the range FROM and
> TO (inclusive).

> TARGET may be a script name symbol.  In that case, use FONT-SPEC for
> all characters that belong to the script.

> TARGET may be a charset.  In that case, use FONT-SPEC for all
> characters in the charset.

> TARGET may be nil.  In that case, use FONT-SPEC for any characters for
> that no FONT-SPEC is specified.

- docs about checking [charsets](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Charsets.html):

> There are two commands that can be used to obtain information about charsets. The command M-x list-charset-chars prompts for a charset name, and displays all the characters in that character set. The command M-x describe-character-set prompts for a charset name, and displays information about that charset, including its internal representation within Emacs.

> To find out which charset a character in the buffer belongs to, put point before it and type C-u C-x =

In our init file we should be able to set one font for full range of characters:

```el
 (let ((my-font "DejaVu Sans Mono-14"))
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-startup" '(#x000000 . #x3FFFFF) my-font)
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" '(#x000000 . #x3FFFFF) my-font)
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-standard" '(#x000000 . #x3FFFFF) my-font))
```

But to set a font for a range of characters and **force it as a fallback font for characters not supported by it** we also must **add** `nil` as a target:

```el
(let ((my-font "DejaVu Sans Mono-14")
      (font-sets '("fontset-default"
                   "fontset-standard"
                   "fontset-startup")))
  (mapcar
   (lambda (font-set)
     ;; all the characters in that range (which is the full possible range)
     (set-fontset-font font-set '(#x000000 . #x3FFFFF) my-font)

     ;; for all characters without font specification
     ;; in another words it is a setting for lack of fallback font
     ;; if e.g. ℕ called DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL N is not covered by our font
     ;; it will be displayed as placeholder-box,
     ;; because fallback for our font is now... our font :)
     (set-fontset-font font-set nil my-font))
   font-sets))
```

Now as we can see under point (cursor) with `C-u C-x =` or `M-x describe-char`:

```
             position: 1430 of 1954 (73%), column: 16
            character: ℕ (displayed as ℕ) (codepoint 8469, #o20425, #x2115)
    preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x2115
               script: symbol
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Left-to-right (strong)
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET HEX-CODEPOINT" or "C-x 8 RET NAME"
          buffer code: #xE2 #x84 #x95
            file code: #xE2 #x84 #x95 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: no font available

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL N
  old-name: DOUBLE-STRUCK N
  general-category: Lu (Letter, Uppercase)
  decomposition: (font 78) (font 'N')
```

Important part: **display: no font available**.

It should be possible to set that in our *.Xresources* file:

> With the X resource ‘Emacs.Font’, you can specify a fontset name
> just like an actual font name.

I do not know what is a proper syntax for that though.

Before that change I was able to see a lot of unicode glyphs not supported by my font of choice.
After that change — I can only see one font in my Emacs and empty boxes-placeholders for glyphs not supported by it.

It works in my system and **should be enough for now before someone
else give you a detailed, technical and correct answer**.

Comment: Your explanation makes good sense, but the actual suggestion configuration doesn't seem to work.  I can't try using the Xresources approach because I'm using the Cocoa build of Emacs on OS X, but setting the fontset fonts as you suggested seems to have no effect.

If I `list-fontsets` after putting your code in my init file, I see four listed and only one is related to the font I set.

Comment: I should clarify: this mysteriously seems to fix the problem for a chunk of glyphs, but not all of them.  I get probably 75% of characters in the font I want, but still a fallback for a select few.

Comment: Yes, that is only valid for *'unicode* range. If you want more encodings covered then you should also change fontsets for them. I will update my answer, but this is probably some hackery. We need to wait for an answer from the Elders of Emacs. :)

Comment: I really appreciate the help so far and am close to marking your answer as accepted, save one final problem.  The main character I keep noticing that this doesn't work for, even after the helpful modification, is the "double struck capital N" used to denote the set of natural numbers.  If I examine it with `describe-char` it seems to be unicode with a code point in the range you've used, but it still displays with a different font.

Comment: I tested ℕ symbol (with *name: DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL N* as showed by inspecting that character with `C-u C-x =`) and I was able to eliminate it. We need to add *nil* target to our rules. Check my update. Cheers.

Comment: In other words we need to say — use my font for the whole range of characters, **but if my font does not support a character, then do not fallback to another font, but also use my font**. ;)

Comment: That last update gave me everything I wanted---marked as solved.  Thanks for your help.